# How to handle a w3c validator report and fix errors

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Since my web page at [www.mobo-fahrschule.ch](http://www.mobo-fahrschule.ch) isn't displayed correct on my nexus7 (no scrollbars), I tried to check if my syntax is correct.

I once run my page through the w3c validator and got a horrible report (26 errors). Unfortunately I'm not even able to fix the first error about `<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="de">`. Whenever I search the web for corrections I get answers the statement is correct but none how to specify on the root element, as the report tells me.

So far I though I'm a rather capable web developer yet either the validator tells me bullshit or I'm completely out of sync with the new technologies. Could anybody point me to the right sources so I'm able to "fix" those errors? Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Most of those errors are about using inline CSS and attributes which should be easy to fix.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H57.html

Answer (score 3):

For the `<meta>` error : the language definition is now set on the root element, like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="de">
    <!-- content -->
<html>
```

Many of those errors come from obsolete use, like `align`, `width`, `cellpadding`, `cellspacing` (...) attributes. You're using an HTML5 doctype, then you shouldn't use xHTML attributes. The validator doesn't tell you bullshit, you're out of sync.

You should have a look on [HTML5 specifications](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/), and on [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) (a front-end template in which you'll find many answers and usefull stuff).

To know all differences between HTML4 and HTML5, please have a look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/).

Comment: Well I might be out of sync, yet neither of your links helps me much further. E.g. where in havens sake is the new syntax for "colgroup"  in the HTML5 specifications? When I look at other web pages I'm by far not the only one who hasen't found it. Aren't there any better resources on the web?

Comment: You can find obsolete attributes [on this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-attributes) (added to my post). More generally, every attribute which have a CSS equivalent is deprecated in HML5.